# Requetsts module python - proxy issue differing across PCs

Tags: python, python-requests

On my local laptop, I am using the requests module to query a Veeva API.

Both my local Windows laptop and the Windows server we are deploying to have the same http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables set.

This works on my local laptop, but strangely I have to delete the environment variables at the top of the script for it to work.

```
import sys
import os
import requests


for k in list(os.environ.keys()):
    if k.lower().endswith('_proxy'):
        del os.environ[k]
        
        

try:
    response = requests.post('https://my.veevavault.com/api/v22.1/auth', 
                             headers={                             
                                 'Accept': 'application/json'
                             }, 
                             data={
                                 'username': 'fred',
                                 'password':'xxx'
                             }
                            )
except Exception as inst:
    print(inst)
    sys.exit(0)

if response.status_code == 200:
    session_id = response.json()["sessionId"]
    print(f"session_id: {session_id}")


   
query = requests.post("https://my.veevavault.com/api/v22.1/query",
        headers={
            'Authorization': session_id,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'X-VaultAPI-DescribeQuery': 'true'
        },
        data = {
            'q': 'SELECT  name__v FROM table__v'
        }                     
)


print(query)
print(query.json())
```

Not sure why I need this locally:

```
for k in list(os.environ.keys()):
    if k.lower().endswith('_proxy'):
        del os.environ[k]
```

When I deploy to the server, I have to remove the code above which deletes the environment variables for it to work.  Very confused....